# How can I split image data in a file into two files without extension in python

Tags: python, machine-learning, split

Hi I'm doing a ML and I want to split image data in one file into two files without extension. I know if it's  a csv file, I can do that using 'to_csv', but for a file without extension I don't.
I mean like one file containing image data become two file containing image data.

```
raw_data →　train_data, test_data
```

How should I do?

Comment: I believe keras has a flowfromdirectory api that allows you to already preset the images into classes.https://keras.io/api/preprocessing/image/

Comment: Thank you for replying Mr Jason. Okay!, then let me try